# How to get the current user agent used by WebView before load an url?

Tags: flutter, webview, user-agent

I'm looking for a way to get the actual Flutter Webview User Agent before loading an url.
It seems not be possible...

Comment: would be nice if you share some code... or can u show us your webview plugin you are using?

Comment: I've no code to share. I use the official flutter webview plugin : https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter

Answer (score 0):

```dart
WebView(
  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController controller) {
    controller
      .runJavascriptReturningResult('navigator.userAgent')
      .then((String currentUserAgent) {
        controller.loadUrl('https://stackoverflow.com/q/70882313/17473716');
      }
  }
)
```

I am not an expert of Flutter.